# Label1.text without clicking to update value

Tags: c#

I am using a label to tell a user if he's logged in to a website or isn't. So what I have done is a added a label and used a if/else statement. But the thing is. I want 1 link label to have two text values

> "logged in" && "Logged out."

So here's the problem. I have the code but I have to click the label before it update the label value:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (1 == 2)
    {
        label1.Text = "Logged out";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Logged in";
    }

}
```

I can't find another one where I could put the code so I don't have to click it. Also, ignore the if(1==2) I have just done that for debugging.

Thank you.

Comment: @Vlad, I assume its ASP.Net since he is saying "logged in to a website"

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put that in the Page_Load event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating your site using Visual Studio + ASP.

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
```

Then there is a tool in the toolbox for this.

Or you can add this to page load.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //Code
    }
}
```